# Can a child process wait for the parent process to terminate in Linux programming in C?

Tags: c, linux, unix

In C programming for Linux, I know the `wait()` function is used to wait for the child process to terminate, but are there some ways (or functions) for child processes to wait for parent process to terminate?

Comment: Create a pipe between the parent and child. When the parent terminates, the child will read EOF from the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no.

A parent process can control the terminal or process group of its children, which is why we have the `wait()` and `waitpid()` functions.  A child doesn't have that kind of control over its parent, so there's nothing built in for that.

If you really need a child to know when its parent exits, you can have the parent send a signal to the child in an `atexit()` handler, and have the child catch that signal.

Answer (score 10):

Linux has an extension (as in, non-POSIX functions) for this. Look up `prctl` ("process-related control").

With `prctl`, you can arrange for the child to get a signal when the parent dies. Look for the `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG` operation code used with `prctl`.

For instance, if you set it to the `SIGKILL` signal, it effectively gives us a way to have the children die when a parent dies. But of course, the signal can be something that the child can catch.

`prctl` can do all kinds of other things. It's like an `ioctl` whose target is the process itself: a "process ioctl".

Comment: Also note that you can use `signalfd` to get the signal synchronously via a file descriptor (e.g. to be monitored via `select`) rather than asynchronously via a handler (which allows very few operations safely)

Comment: This is great, thanks! I eventually stumbled upon a race condition, [this issue in unshare](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/issues/1490) explains it well (with fixes).

Comment: @David I think the article is making it overcomplicated. Simply, make the `prctl` call when your process is good and ready for catching the signal, so it doesn't happen at some inconvenient time, like during early process  startup. Then, after making the call, check whether the parent is still alive. If you're sure your program isn't directly spawned by the init daemon (PID 1), you can call `getppid`; if that returns 1, the parent died (causing the process to have been reassigned to PID 1 as its parent.

Comment: @Kaz I think you can't really check against the parent PID being one, as there may be a subreaper registered in the process hierarchy which becomes the parent of the orphaned process (and it's PID != 1). And I suspect just checking whether the parent PID has changed isn't correct in general either. Or at least I wouldn't trust it to work in general.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, you can use prctl with the value PR_SET_PDEATHSIG to establish a signal that will be sent to your process when the **thread** that created it dies. Maybe you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

When a parent process ends, child process is adopted by init, so it is enough to check in child proces if ppid()==1 or ppid()!= than oryginal PPID
That means the parent process was finished.