# Make processes run at the same time using fork

Tags: c, linux, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char buf[600];
    char *pos;
    pid_t parent = fork();
    if(parent == 0) { 
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
            pid_t child = fork();
            if(child == 0) {
                /* is there a function I can put here so that it waits 
                once the parent is exited to then run?*/
                printf("%s\n", buf);
                return(0);

            }

        }
        return(0);
    }
    wait(NULL);
    return(0);

}
```

The goal here to print out the line of a file all at the same time, parallel.

For example:

Given a file

```
a 
b
c


$ gcc -Wall above.c
$ ./a.out file
a
c
b
$ ./a.out file
b
c
a
```

As in the processes ran at the exact same time. I think I can get this to work if there was a wait clause that waits for the parent to exit then start running the child. As shown in the comments above. Once the parent exits then all the processes would start at the print statement as wanted.

Comment: I think we have a different understanding of "at the exact same time". Please explain yours.

Comment: They run in parallel, the order the lines are in doesn't matter, and each line is independent.

Comment: Perhaps *threads* are better suited for your purpose. Do you *have to* use processes?

Comment: Yes processes with fork only

Comment: This post seem to answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723398/can-a-child-process-wait-for-the-parent-process-to-terminate-in-linux-programmin

Comment: Your program doesn't seem to be right anyway. Each of the child process would continue to read the file as well. Shouldn't they just exit if you want each process to print only one line?

Comment: @P.P. the child processes are doing `return` after the `printf`, they don't do anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had:

```
int i = 10;
while (i > 0)
{
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child == 0) {
        printf("i: %d\n", i--);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

then the child processes are running **concurrently**. And depending on the number of cores and your OS scheduler, they might even run literally at the same time. However, `printf` is buffer, so the order in which the lines appear on screen cannot be determined and will vary between executions of your program. And because `printf` is buffered, you will most likely not see lines overlapping other other. However if you were using `write` directly to `stdout`, then the outputs might overlap.

In your scenario however, the children die so fast and because you are reading
from a file (which might take a while to return), by the time the next `fork` is executed,
the previous child is already dead. But that doesn't change the fact, that if
the children would run long enough, they would be running concurrently and the
order of the lines on screen cannot be determined.

**edit**

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49438017/make-processes-run-at-the-same-time-using-fork/49438247#comment85878993_49438247) points out in the comments, `write` is atomic. I looked up in my
man page and in the *BUGS*  section it says this:

> *man 2 write*
>
> According to POSIX.1-2008/SUSv4 Section XSI 2.9.7 ("Thread Interactions with Regular File Operations"):
>
> > *All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when they operate on regular files or symbolic links: ...*
>
> Among the APIs subsequently listed are `write()` and `writev(2)`. And among the effects that should be atomic across threads (and pro‐
>   cesses) are updates of the file offset.  **However, on Linux before version 3.14, this was not the case: if two processes that share an
>   open file description (see `open(2)`) perform a `write()` (or `writev(2)`) at the same time, then the I/O operations were not atomic with
>   respect updating the file offset, with the result that the blocks of data output by the two processes might (incorrectly) overlap.
>   This problem was fixed in Linux 3.14.**

Sever years ago I observed this behaviour of `write` on `stdout` with concurrent
children printing stuff, that's why I wrote that with `write`, the lines may
overlap.

Comment: While `write()` isn't buffered, I think each call would be atomic, so they won't overlap. If you write the text and newline separately, you might get mixing.

Comment: @Barmar my man pages does indeed mention that POSIX demands from  `write` to be atomic but it also mentions that before linux 3.14 this was not the case. I know that in the past I've seen this behaviour that `write` on forked processes overlapped with each other. Thanks, I'll fix my answer

Comment: It probably actually depends on the size of the write. Or maybe it's only for pipes, where a write below `PIPE_BUF` is guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have an outer loop. You could rewrite as follows. Once you create the child processes, they could run in any order. So you might seem the output in "order" but in another run you might see different order. It depends on the process scheduling by your OS and for your purpose, it's all running in "parallel". So you really don't need to ensure parent process is dead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Incorrect args\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[1024];
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file)) {
        pid_t child = fork();
        if(child == 0) {
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, strlen(buf));
            _exit(0);
        }
    }

    /* Wait for all child processes. */
    while (wait(NULL) != -1);
}
```